# Are "dual" and "duel" necessarily homophones?

Tags: pronunciation, homophones

The pronunuciation of the words *dual* and *duel* is generally given in dictionaries as /ˈd(j)uːəl/.

Thus the two words are homophones.

However, saying these words to myself, I think I detect a slight difference.  For me (a native speaker from the northeastern US), *duel* is more like /du:l/.  That is, it would rhyme with *fool* or *stool*, instead of with *fuel.*

Two questions:

1. Does anyone else make this distinction?  Is it a dialectal pronunciation?
2. Does anyone know of English minimal pairs that contrast /-u:əl/ and /-u:l/?

Comment: I kind of make the opposite distinction: I pronounce them *dual* /du:l/ and *duel*:  /dju:əl/. But I think it's the yod I stick in *duel* that leads me to add the schwa; for me, *duel* rhymes with *fuel* and *mule*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're different for me as well. The pronunciation of *duel, cruel, gruel, fuel, jewel* etc. with /u(ː)l/ is a simplification of historical /-u(ː).əl/. This is not a feature of all accents, but I believe it's reasonably common. Wikipedia describes it under the broader category of "[vile-vial merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Vile.E2.80.93vial_merger)," but I'm not sure if this is really a unified phenomenon. Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article doesn't seem to cite any scholarly articles that might give more insight into how prevalent this change is, or which words are most commonly affected.

What I've found is that I don't do this for words ending in *-ual.* So for me, *dual* and *manual* still have /-u(ː).əl/. I suspect this difference in my pronunciation is influenced by the difference in spelling: there are many other words where *ue* represents /uː/, such as *glue,* but I can't think of any words where *ua* represents /uː/. It can't be entirely due to some particular status for the suffix *-al,* since I pronounce *real* and *ideal* with /i(ː)l/; that said, I do use /i(ː).əl/ for some other adjectives ending in "eal" that are less common, such as *periotoneal* /perɪtəˈni.əl/ (from *peritoneum* perɪtəˈni.əm/).

There certainly are minimal pairs for people with either kind of accent. For people with an accent like yours, *duel* /d(j)u(ː)l/and *dual* /d(j)u(ː).əl/ are a minimal pair. For people with accents that always retain traditional /-uː.əl/, *jewel* /dʒuː.əl/ and  *joule* /dʒuːl/ are a minimal pair. There may be other accents that merge all such words to /u(ː)l/ or /u(ː).əl/ without exception.

Comment: Does anybody pronounce *manual* /mænju:l/? I would think that if it gets reduced to two syllables, it would be /mænjəl/.

Comment: @PeterShor: I don't know. The only pronunciations I use are /mænju:əl/ and /mænjəl/, but before you commented, I didn't know anyone consistently pronounced "dual" as /du:l/ and "duel" as /duəl/.

Comment: It's surely accent/dialect and that's it... in my home part of the UK (Wales), we tend to use every letter as written, so *dual* and *duel* are very different. Contrast that to a south Londoner, though, for whom the pronunciation would converge on a single noise for both these and *jewel* (the *dʒu:l* form).

Comment: @ProfYaffle: It's definitely a matter of accent, but meaningful things can still be said about it. I'm currently trying to find a paper that would describe which accents tend to use which pronunciation. Thanks for your descriptions of the UK accents you are familiar with, that is useful information. There are no accents of English where every letter is pronounced as written... that's not even possible, since letters are digital by nature but speech is analog.

Comment: @sumelic Indeed, it's not literally every letter - but the stereotypical Welsh accent is much more particular and emphatic with each syllable, there are few lazy letters, dropped consonants and the like (so it's *lit-er-all-y* with equal emphasis, and not *li'rally* with first-syllable emphasis, or the US *lider-ally* or anything similar). I think we veer off the OP's topic a little here, though, as this is a treatise in itself.